# Comparing 2 arrays using NumPy and returning the index with the lower number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays :

```
A = array([1.48067671, 1.48352177, 1.4481969 ,1.00006692, 1.28575167,1.32976551])
B = array([1.364952  , 1.36871978, 1.33351794,1.17396389, 1.19171093,1.23191085])
```

They are same length - I need to compare each index and determine which array has the lower value.
For example - the result above should be:

```
[B,B,B,A,B,B]
```

Comment: All values in `B` are less than the values of `A`. So why does your expected result contain an `A`?

Comment: Yep - sorry updated the array A to showcase an example where A is smaller than B

Comment: You expected result is a list that contains 5 copies of `B` and one copy of `A`. Is that what you want? Or do you want to select element-wise the smaller value (i.e. `[B[0], B[1], B[2], A[3], B[4], B[5]]`)?

Comment: If A = 0th array and B = 1st array then the result would be : [1,1,1,0,1,1]. I specifically do not need the actual values in the resultant array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask and cast to `int`:

```
(B < A).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked. Marked as correct. Just a follow up what if there are dynamic number of arrays ? For example: arrays = [A,B,C] where A , B ,C are arrays like above. How can I make the above (B < A).astype(int) generic?

Comment: @PythonLearner You can `stack` and use `argmin` like `np.stack((A, B, C)).argmin(axis=0)`.